# 416 or 206 when Range start === current resource size?

Tags: rest, http

Given https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233#section-4.4 I am unsure what should happen if the `Range` start is the same as the current resource size?

e.g. `bytes 100-` and resource size is 100 bytes should I return a 206 (`content-length` === 0) or a 416?

Comment: the first byte is byte 0, so a 100 byte resource has bytes 0-99 and therefore a range starting at 100 is off the end - unsatisfiable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Byte ranges are 0-based indexed.

So the range of a 100 byte resource is 0-99

A request on a 100 byte resource, with request header Range: bytes 100- is asking for the 101st byte onwards.  In a 100 byte resource this is unsatisfiable, and the correct status to return is 416

Comment: Yes, but what if Range: bytes 99- ?

Comment: That's not what you asked. 99- is 1 byte (the last one) which you can satisfy